# Is parallelism usefull with a lock for datatable write transactions

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, strongly-typed-dataset

Will parallelism help with performance for a locked object, should it be run single threaded, or is there another technique?

I noticed that when accessing a dataset and adding rows from multiple threads exceptions were thrown.  Therefore I created a "thread-safe" version to add rows by locking the table prior to updating the row.  This implementation works but is appears slow with many transactions.

```
public partial class HaMmeRffl
{
    public partial class PlayerStatsDataTable
    {
        public void AddPlayerStatsRow(int PlayerID, int Year, int StatEnum, int Value, DateTime Timestamp)
        {
            lock (TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats)
            {
                HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow testrow = TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.FindByPlayerIDYearStatEnum(PlayerID, Year, StatEnum);
                if (testrow == null)
                {
                    HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow newRow = TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.NewPlayerStatsRow();
                    newRow.PlayerID = PlayerID;
                    newRow.Year = Year;
                    newRow.StatEnum = StatEnum;
                    newRow.Value = Value;
                    newRow.Timestamp = Timestamp;
                    TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.AddPlayerStatsRow(newRow);
                }
                else
                {
                    testrow.Value = Value;
                    testrow.Timestamp = Timestamp;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can call this safely from multiple threads, but does it actually buy me anything? Can I do this differently for better performance.  For instance is there any way to use `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace to optimize performance or any other methods?

In addition, I update the underlying database after the entire dataset is updated and that takes a very long time.  Would that be considered an I/O operation and be worth using parallel processing by updating it after each row is updated in the dataset (or some number of rows).

**UPDATE**

I wrote some code to test concurrent vs sequential processing which shows it takes about 30% longer to do concurrent processing and I should use sequential processing here. **I assume this is because the lock on the database is causing the overhead on the `ConcurrentQueue` to be more costly than the gains from parallel processing.  Is this conclusion correct and is there anything that I can do to speed up the processing**, or am I stuck as for a `Datatable` "You must synchronize any write operations".

Here is my test code which might not be scientifically correct.  Here is the timer and calls between them.

```
            dbTimer.Restart();
            Queue<HaMmeRffl.PlayersRow.PlayerValue> addPlayerRow = InsertToPlayerQ(addUpdatePlayers);
            Queue<HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow.PlayerStatValue> addPlayerStatRow                     = InsertToPlayerStatQ(addUpdatePlayers);
            UpdatePlayerStatsInDB(addPlayerRow, addPlayerStatRow);
            dbTimer.Stop();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Writing to the dataset took {0} seconds single threaded", dbTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

            dbTimer.Restart();
            ConcurrentQueue<HaMmeRffl.PlayersRow.PlayerValue> addPlayerRows                    = InsertToPlayerQueue(addUpdatePlayers);
            ConcurrentQueue<HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow.PlayerStatValue> addPlayerStatRows                    = InsertToPlayerStatQueue(addUpdatePlayers);
            UpdatePlayerStatsInDB(addPlayerRows, addPlayerStatRows);
            dbTimer.Stop();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Writing to the dataset took {0} seconds concurrently", dbTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

In both examples I add to the `Queue` and `ConcurrentQueue` in an identical manner single threaded.  The only difference is the insertion into the datatable.  The single-threaded approach inserts as follows:

```
    private static void UpdatePlayerStatsInDB(Queue<HaMmeRffl.PlayersRow.PlayerValue> addPlayerRows, Queue<HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow.PlayerStatValue> addPlayerStatRows)
    {
        try
        {
            HaMmeRffl.PlayersRow.PlayerValue row;
            while (addPlayerRows.Count > 0)
            {
                row = addPlayerRows.Dequeue();
                TeamMemberData.Dataset.Players.AddPlayersRow(
                    row.PlayerID, row.Name, row.PosEnum, row.DepthEnum,
                    row.TeamID, row.RosterTimestamp, row.DepthTimestamp,
                    row.Active, row.NewsUpdate);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            TeamMemberData.Dataset.Players.RejectChanges();
        }

        try
        {
            HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow.PlayerStatValue row;
            while (addPlayerStatRows.Count > 0)
            {
                row = addPlayerStatRows.Dequeue();
                TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.AddUpdatePlayerStatsRow(
                    row.PlayerID, row.Year, row.StatEnum, row.Value, row.Timestamp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.RejectChanges();
        }

        TeamMemberData.Dataset.Players.AcceptChanges();
        TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.AcceptChanges();

    }
```

The concurrent adds as follows

```
    private static void UpdatePlayerStatsInDB(ConcurrentQueue<HaMmeRffl.PlayersRow.PlayerValue> addPlayerRows, ConcurrentQueue<HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow.PlayerStatValue> addPlayerStatRows)
    {
        Action actionPlayer = () =>
        {
            HaMmeRffl.PlayersRow.PlayerValue row;
            while (addPlayerRows.TryDequeue(out row))
            {
                TeamMemberData.Dataset.Players.AddPlayersRow(
                    row.PlayerID, row.Name, row.PosEnum, row.DepthEnum,
                    row.TeamID, row.RosterTimestamp, row.DepthTimestamp,
                    row.Active, row.NewsUpdate);
            }
        };

        Action actionPlayerStat = () =>
        {
            HaMmeRffl.PlayerStatsRow.PlayerStatValue row;
            while (addPlayerStatRows.TryDequeue(out row))
            {
                TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.AddUpdatePlayerStatsRow(
                    row.PlayerID, row.Year, row.StatEnum, row.Value, row.Timestamp);
            }
        };

        Action[] actions = new Action[Environment.ProcessorCount * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
        {
            actions[i * 2] = actionPlayer;
            actions[i * 2 + 1] = actionPlayerStat;
        }

        try
        {
            // Start ProcessorCount concurrent consuming actions.
            Parallel.Invoke(actions);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            TeamMemberData.Dataset.Players.RejectChanges();
            TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.RejectChanges();
        }

        TeamMemberData.Dataset.Players.AcceptChanges();
        TeamMemberData.Dataset.PlayerStats.AcceptChanges();

    }
```

The difference in time is 4.6 seconds for the single-threaded and 6.1 for the parallel.Invoke.

Comment: You may want to look in to some kind of message queue system and have a single thread handle all of the database/data table actions while the rest of the program can continue on after its puts it's action on the queue.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thats what I'm looking at now.  I was going with `ConcurrentQueue` and was going to attempt to use multiple threads to try to speed up the database transactions, but then was wondering if I should just use a regular queue and a single thread

Comment: The full implementation depends on how you are doing your whole project (for example are there other functions besides `AddPlayerStatsRow`). The simplest way to do it is a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) backed by a `ConcurrentQueue` running on it's own thread, (you just call `GetConsumingEnumerable()` in a foreach loop and you just let it run forever). More complicated solutions can involve writing your own extension to [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Lock & transactions are not good for parallelism and performance.

1)Try avoid lock：Will different threads need to update the same Row in dataset?

2)minimize lock time.

For db operation use may try Batch Update future of ADO.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810297.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately when I did this without a lock I was getting exceptions.  I do update the same row in a dataset with different threads at times.  I don't see how I can avoid locking the associated table.  I do believe I have the lock the smallest I can as it's basically a wrapper around the default Addrow method, do you see room for improvement in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading  can help upto an extent because once the data across your app boundary ,    you    will start waiting for I/O , here you can do asynchronous processing because your app  does not have control over various parameters ( Resource access , Network speed etc),this will give better user experience (If UI app).

Now for your scenario , you may want to use some sort of producer/consumer queue , as soon as a row is available in queue , a different thread start processing it but again this will work upto an extent.